# Altair make axis lines thicker

Tags: python, charts, visualization, altair, vega-lite

I have an altair chart that looks like below. I would like to make the axis lines thicker as I (read: the reviewer of my paper) feel the current lines are too thin and are not easily visible on the screen. I tried looking at the [Top-Level Chart Configuration](https://altair-viz.github.io/altair-viz-v4/user_guide/configuration.html#config-view), but I couldn't find anything that would allow me to do that. The closest thing I found that to use `.configure_view(strokeWidth=4, stroke='black')`, that makes the entire chart border thicker but I want just the axis lines to be thicker.

How do I make the axis lines thicker? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is controlled by domainWidth. e.g.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.movies.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("IMDB_Rating:Q", bin=True, axis=alt.Axis(domainWidth=10)),
    y='count()',
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I must admit its an unintuitive name. And the [docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/altair-viz-v4/user_guide/configuration.html#axis-configuration) don't say what its used for.